# 64 bit fails to load-get a 32bit OS instead

Tags: 13.10, 64-bit, system-installation

I  have a new 64 bit computer that I finished building yesterday.  I am using the Ubuntu disk that came with the book 'Ubuntu Unleashed'.  It has loaded a 32 bit OS three times in a row.  Any help?

Comment: You do not mention which edition of the book you have. But as the latest edition ships with *DVD includes the full Ubuntu 13.10 distribution for Intel x86* I'm assuming that previous editions ship with x86, too, that is 32bit binaries. For 64bit you need amd64, you can get it from http://www.ubuntu.com

Comment: @Adaephon I'd add that as an answer :)

Comment: @Seth: thanks for the suggestion, I just did so. I wasn't sure whether to answer or comment.

Answer (score 1):

My piece of advice is to go to www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop and download the 64-bit image :)

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the latest edition of *Ubuntu Unleashed* ships with a DVD that *includes the full Ubuntu 13.10 distribution for Intel x86* (according to [this site](http://www.informit.com/store/ubuntu-unleashed-2014-edition-covering-13.10-and-14-9780672336935)). I'm assuming that previous editions ship with *x86*, too.

In this case *x86* stands for 32-bit binaries. So if you install from this medium, you'll get a 32-bit operating system. Ubuntu does not have binaries for multiple architectures (like for example Mac OS X), so there is no automatic selection on boot or even installation time. You have to choose your architecture by using the matching installation medium.

For 64-bit you need *amd64* (also known as *x86-64* or - rarely - *EMT64*, yes it can be confusing). You can get it from [ubuntu.com](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop). Just select *64-bit* on the version you want.